# React redirect to page using handle submit and pass message

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect

I am trying to build a simple website where it takes in a message, and passes the message in the url into the next page after it hits submit.

below is what i have so far, it does not pass my message into my `welcomePage`

```
class HomePage extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {message: ''};
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.updateInput = this.updateInput.bind(this);
  }
  updateInput(event){
    this.setState({message : event.target.value})
    }
  handleSubmit = e =>  {
    e.preventDefault();
    let msg = this.state.message;
    let path = `/welcome/?message=${msg}/`;
    console.log(path)
    this.props.history.push(path) //trying to redirect to this path with the message
  } 
  render(){
    return (
      <div className='HomePage'>
        <header>Home</header>
        <p>
          Hello, please enter a welcome message: 
          <br/>
          <input type="text"
            className="form-control" 
            name="message"
            onChange={this.updateInput}/>
            <button className="submit" 
              type="submit" 
              onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
                Submit
            </button>
        </p>
      </div>
      );
  }
}
```

Below is the welcome page which is supposed to take the mesaage from home page and display, but right now it says welcome, undefined instead of just welcome, when its empty, and it never picks up the message as i get an error.

I would also like if i do something like
/welcome/?message=hello%20how%20are%20you
the welcome page will display that message directly, regardless if i went to the homepage for input or not.

```
class WelcomePage extends React.Component {
  render(){
  return <p>{`Welcome! ${this.input}`}</p>} //trying to get the message from the url here, so it displays
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where does the `this.input` come from? it comes from nowhere, so its value is undefined of course.

You should get the message value by parsing the url, you can try this:

```js
class WelcomePage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const msg = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('message')
    return <p>{`Welcome! ${msg}`}</p>
  }
}
```

---

Full works sample code with react-router(v5.2.0) in https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-villani-2rnc8?file=/src/App.js:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Router, Route, Switch, withRouter } from "react-router";
import "./styles.css";

import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

const customHistory = createBrowserHistory();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router history={customHistory}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <HomePage />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/welcome">
          <WelcomePage />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

class _HomePage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { message: "" };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.updateInput = this.updateInput.bind(this);
  }
  updateInput(event) {
    this.setState({ message: event.target.value });
  }
  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let msg = this.state.message;
    let path = `/welcome?message=${msg}`;
    console.log(path);
    this.props.history.push(path); //trying to redirect to this path with the message
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="HomePage">
        <header>Home</header>
        <p>
          Hello, please enter a welcome message:
          <br />
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            name="message"
            onChange={this.updateInput}
          />
          <button className="submit" type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
            Submit
          </button>
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const HomePage = withRouter(_HomePage);

class _WelcomePage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const msg = new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search).get("message");
    console.log(msg);
    return <p>{`Welcome! ${msg}`}</p>;
  }
}

const WelcomePage = withRouter(_WelcomePage);
```

Comment: hi there, im still getting: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: if you want to use `this.props.history.push(path)`, you must use react-router together, but I suggest you use `history.pushState(null, '', path)` without react-router to make the code pass temporary.

Comment: could you elaborate on how to use react-router together in this case?

Comment: maybe the react-router document can help you: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/query-parameters

Comment: I tried doing it like that but am still getting confused as my example is a bit different from what was provided. what do you suggest putting instead of using this.props.history.push?

Comment: Just tried in codesandbox.io, you can have a look: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-villani-2rnc8?file=/src/App.js